# html_safe in ruby on rails not working

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, ruby-on-rails-4, html-safe

I'm using ruby 2.0.0
This is my controller..

```
@mail_msg = @store_items.where(id: params[:button_id]).first.email_confirmation_text
p "-------------------------"
p @mail msg
p @mail_msg.html_safe
```

This is my console(terminal) output

```
"-------------------------"
"<p>You have purchased Spice It Up. Points have been redeemed from your main account.</p>"
"<p>You have purchased Spice It Up. Points have been redeemed from your main account.</p>"
```

And what im getting in my console is the same. I cant escape the html tags.

### Update

I have this value in my view..
in my view page

```
<%= @mail_msg.html_safe %>
```

Still its not working..

Please help

Comment: Try it in view it will work

Comment: should work in views where html is used. you are using html in controller? haven't seen that yet

Comment: yes because the html_safe is a helper method.

Comment: If you are using html_safe in the controller as `@mail_msg.html_safe` then in views just give it as `<%= @mail_msg %>`.It will work.

Comment: You misunderstand what `html_safe` is for. It marks a string as "safe for inclusion in HTML" so that the template system won't HTML-encode it.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Try these one may will help you

```
strip_tags("Strip <i>these</i> tags!")
```

*# => Strip these tags!*

```
strip_tags("<b>Bold</b> no more!  <a href='more.html'>See more here</a>...")
```

*# => Bold no more!  See more here...*

```
strip_tags("<div id='top-bar'>Welcome to my website!</div>")
```

*# => Welcome to my website!`enter code here`*

Comment: I've never seen `strip_tags` anywhere.Can provide a `link` to support your answer?

Comment: http://api.rubyonrails.org/classes/ActionView/Helpers/SanitizeHelper.html#method-i-strip_tags

Answer (score 2):

`html_safe` and `raw` work in views, use

```
<%= raw @mail_msg %>
```

or

```
<%= @mail_msg.html_safe %>
```